# Why is there a staggering amount of unanswered microphone-related questions using ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Since **Ubuntu's 20.04** official release, I've seen more and more questions related to **microphone** not being detected, white noise, headsets with only speakers working and etc, especially in the first few months of the release.

Most of the questions remain unanswered, and even new questions that pop every day remain unanswered.

I can't assess the actual amount of such questions as not all are correctly tagged, but when [querying the microphone tag with the 20.04 search string](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bmicrophone%5D20.04), we may find around 130 matching questions and **only few are answered**, let alone accepted.

**It is also to be noted** that the 2 most answered questions ([Q1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260928/no-speakers-no-microphone-but-headphones-dell-lattitude-e6530-20-04) , [Q2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262607/ubuntu-20-04-internal-microphone-is-not-working-input-device-drop-down-menu-is) ) contain many different possible solutions and comments, which differ greatly one from another. It seems like there are no common known solutions you can mark questions as duplicate or suggest in the comments with them.

It also seems that **there was a known bug** when upgrading the system to 20.04 after its release ([Q3)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237885/kazam-microphone-unknown), but I'm sure that's not the cause for all or even most of the questions since then.

I personally did not encounter such problems, but is there an actual list of common problems with verified common solutions that may help answering such questions?

Comment: You are welcome to compile such a list. It would help us all.

Comment: Ironically this will be yet another one in the long line of unanswered questions apparently.

Comment: @MoffKalast lol good one

Comment: This is largely skewed, even if there were microphone bugs, due to COVID and video conferences. I would assume that pre-COVID most people using Ubuntu didn't do many video calls, could be wrong though.

Comment: Also please add any thoughts to my semi-related question [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19466/should-we-have-a-canon-dupe-for-microphone-problems).

Answer (score 4):

It's probably due to these factors:

- There are more and more people working from home, due to Covid-19, and they are taking more remote calls
- Maybe there are more Ubuntu users generally
- Ubuntu's handling of microphones is still pretty buggy. I certainly am experiencing problems with the microphone on Ubuntu.