# Should we have a canon dupe for microphone problems?

Tags: discussion

[Recently](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19323/1122556) there have been a [large number](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=microphone) of questions related to microphones not being recognized or not working in some way, most of them liekly due to COVID-19 making people work from home. While the answer could *largely* vary from mic to mic and install to install, it seems to me like it would be a good idea to have a community wiki (or several for different problems, e.g. not showing up vs bad quality vs silent) with possible/common solutions to these problems. Any thoughts?

Comment: The microphones have caught a virus?

Answer (score 5):

Let's not close all microphone issues as duplicates. There are different microphone issues with different solutions. If we close them all  as duplicates pointing to just one post, we will frustrate a lot of people who cannot fix their issue using the answers on that post.

I like the idea of having a good question and answer post to troubleshoot all microphone issues, but I doubt it will be good enough to satisfy all the people having microphone issues. If you think otherwise, please point me to a page or post that is good enough to resolve everybody's issues.

Comment: In other words, let's make the canon dupe first, and then decide whether we should start closing things as duplicates.